# Update screwing with encrypted disk or keep using windows boot?

Tags: high-sierra, startup, filevault

On my 2011 macbook air i have high sierra installed.

It attempted and at some point completed an update **security update 2010-001** to **version 10.13.6** (not sure if i had automatic updates on or not).

Because i had disk encryption on, i think it became befouled.

Something like what is discussed here:

http://discussions.apple.com/thread/8092225

[forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79420](http://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79420)

I now have trouble booting (often it doesnt boot and it takes ages when it does).

I tried clearing the flash with (cmd+optn+P+R) without much help.

On the odd occasion it eventually boots, but as with others on that page everything was going real slow and so i tried to start decrypting the disk (turning off file vault encryption) as others suggested on that page.

Now it is taking a real long time to decrypt. I left it on overnight and had sleep turned off, nevertheless it still locked my computer and i think maybe made no progress over night.

So i got it to boot into my install of windows via bootcamp, and windows works fine. So my question is, should i just use my Mac as a windows machine? or is Apple working on a fix for this problem?

I was able to do a FirstAid via DiskUtility on two different occasions. The first time (before i started decrypting) it came up with errors. The second time after i started decryption, it seemed to complete fine.

I was able to get into recovery mode where i could reinstall the O.S but it wont allow me because indefinite decryption is occuring.

High Sierra is basically not functional/fast now and decrytion is taking forever.

Will i need to wipe the whole disk or will the decryption eventually finish?

Comment: Is Windows using encryption?

Comment: i dont think so

Comment: Why is it acceptable for you to use Window without encryption, but you needed encryption when using macOS? Why not install macOS without encryption and continue to use macOS?

Comment: @DavidAnderson i only use windows rarely for windows dev. i dont have any private data on that volume. and besides, if i knew file vault encryption would f up my volume on update, i may not have used it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

I noticed `safe boot (hold shift)` WAS working fine with CPU available but limited by the fact it doesnt load everything.

I then did [Justin Silvers](https://www.justinsilver.com/technology/os-x-el-capitan-10-11-1-hanging-on-boot-fixed/) method of removing older kexts. 
Particularly previous to that i was only managing kexts under `/Library` and `~/Library` but now i was also removing older ones from `/System/Library`.

One of the kexts i removed was PACEsupport and i also moved other Mbox2 related old kexts. These were from pre 2015.

But this didnt fix things immediately and not even after restart, but it did force the cache to rebuild itself from scratch as i watch it do so in `verbose boot mode (cmd+v)`.

So i went out to buy a replacement cord as i had given up on fixing the O.S and was going to try to get my old external HD to restore an old snapshot if possible, then suddenly out of the blue it released CPU resources again & now kernel is processing fine again & now i just need to find the correct way to recognise my old external HD.

At the time it released resources it seemed to be processing a lot of `QuickLookSatellite` processes & i took a snapshot here.
As you can see the kernel was using all the CPU (at times up to 1300% or more) and here it falls off the cliff back to 18% seemingly randomly but i think it just finally processed all the kext cache again and maybe some of the removed kexts were no longer preventing it. But i think there were several kexts that were problematic here particularly originally the `Commander` uninstall kext process was DDoSing the kernel CPU.

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

indeed the problem returned. 
however i was able to fix it by doing the below.

After the disk decryption process finished, i still couldn't reinstall the O.S through recovery boot, because of connection to apple server problems, even after fixing datetime synchronisation problems.

I was however able to get my system functioning again by removing some startup items and daemons that i think were flooding my system CPU usage. I found these via inspecting the console (in utility folder) and by using EtreCheck tool.

Effectively a couple of older kexts were continually polling my O.S kernel (particularly one called `Commander`, associated with an old WIFI dongle uninstall process and another one associate with an old program called `NoSleep` that would prevent the O.S from sleeping but was designed for an older O.S).

These mustve been in conflict with kernel changes in high sierra + update. So they were effectively DDOSing my O.S and consequently kernel CPU was flooded. Stopping these and removing a bunch of unneeded kexts seems to have fixed the problem into a functional O.S again. Im unsure if it was only those two kexts or other removed kexts that ultimately fixed the problem, but at least this gives you an idea of what to do if you have the same problem.

**Resources:**

[osxdaily.com/2011/-3/08/remove-an-agent-from-launchd](http://osxdaily.com/2011/-3/08/remove-an-agent-from-launchd)

[etrecheck.com](http://etrecheck.com)

**Result:**
My bootup time became faster but seemingly not yet back to pre-problem speed.
However, the O.S is now completely functional again, with idle CPU kernal usage down to minimal and user CPU usage available again.

---

**Originally accepted answer:**

> strangely enough, i used my windows boot for a few days, and even did
>   a windows update, then i tried to boot Mac again and its working
>   mostly fine now, it still took a bit slower to boot (but not 20
>   minutes like it was doing before), and the decrypting is not even
>   finished now. So apart from not using the volume for a few days, i
>   have no idea why it is now working seemingly well again. Id suggest if
>   you have a similar problem to look at the links i've posted in the
>   question details. Perhaps just accessing the boot sector with Windows
>   helped fix up some files or perhaps it was the last First Aid i was
>   manage to do which didnt immediately fix it but mayve fixed it but
>   took a few boots for me to realise. its also possible the problem is
>   not fully fixed and will return but im offering this as the answer for
>   now.

Comment: Have you ever replaced the hd?  Harddrives go downhill over time.  I'd run etrecheck. The proprietary stuff gets filtered. It has basic tests for harddrives.

-- Download etrecheck.  Then click on the download link at the bottom of the screen.
http://etrecheck.com/

-- Run etrecheck.   The first five runs are free.

-- Using EtreCheck by etresoft, the author
https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-11591

Comment: i doubt it was the HD itself, otherwise i wonder why its working now. i havent had any such problem for some years and it seemed to coincide with the security update. my hard drive was pretty full at the time of the incident, its possible a memory overflow caused it or if the security update began itself that may have triggered the issue too. i will try the etrecheck though, i recall using that tool for something else at some stage.

Comment: It's a weird situation. I don't encrypt my hd, because recovery is harder.  But everyone's security needs are different.

Comment: true. well i cant even remember why i encrypted mine, i dont really need it either. but indeed the problem reoccured. hopefully another few days of using windows again will fix it again. windows, it just works. :(

Comment: update: after decryotion process finished, i still couldnt reinstall the O.S, because of connection to apple server problems, even after fixing datetime synch. I was however able to get my system functioning again by removing some startup items that i think were flooding my system CPU usage. Effectively a couple of older kexts (that mustve been in conflict with kernel changes in high sierra + update) were DDOSing my O.S. Stopping these and removing a bunch of unneeded kexts seems to have fixed the problem into a functional O.S again. Bootup time=faster but not back to pre-problem speed.

Comment: Install etrecheck.  Run.  Post results here.

Comment: Sure I will do that's specially since the problem has returned, that is i.think the call to the uninstall process for Commander is lingering somewhere that the simple remove kext hasn't completely removed. I've found another post listing other folders I'm going to attempt to peruse. The biggest problem is I can barely run.anyhting at all. But I did get an etre scan done before posting the update and will attempt to do another now.

Comment: I ran etrecheck results here: https://pastebin.com/1xgFHKs5

Comment: the etrecheck scan points to openssl kext and NTPD agent being problematic, the latter making sense cos the datetime wasnt working when i attempted OS reinstall and it couldnt contact apples servers.  but ive regained at least 7% user CPU now by somehow disabling the Commander uninstall plist or startup item

Comment: I really am confused about whats happening. When I do `top` I can't see any process hogging all the CPU yet it reports 3-6% user CPU and the rest as system CPU. This is already after I've stopped the commander uninstall call respawning again. I also noticed what seems to be a bunch of network activity I don't recognise when looking at `all.messages` on my device in console. They're all under WebKit networking with many connections being made. Is it possible I have a DNS virus?

Comment: now it seems to have seemingly randomly released CPU resources again. i think its cos it gets to process all the startup items but when the rogue kexts are calling it is blocking the processing of the rest of them and becomes a race. i tried to do a search for the commander domain and now hopefully everything is gone. or it may be that the kernel extension sector has become abit corrupted since the update.

Comment: Again the problem reoccurred. This time I found again Commander uninstall was spamming and I found there was a leftover Commander plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents and I deleted but it doesnt immediately free up CPU. I also found `Keychain Circle Notification` not responding like here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7502179

Comment: Furthermore it seems apple has not allowed update to Mojave from my MBA (2011) which means any possible fixes they put into that are not available to me and others in my position. So they put out a security update that screws peoples system and then only way to fix (apart from wiping and starting again) seems to be to buy a new pc. Sounds like planned obsolecense. No care for whether people were doing important work on their machine and haven't backed up yet either.

Comment: If you're in this position I recommend to search both /Library and ~/Library from the terminal for the rogue kext, which you can find as the spamming one in console. Then remove it. Then just wait until hopefully it releases the resources again and maybe restart computer. Apple should test their updates on target machines and not just assume they will be backwards compatible. Might look at Ubuntu next PC I buy.

Comment: Seems not just my problem: https://www.justinsilver.com/technology/os-x-el-capitan-10-11-1-hanging-on-boot-fixed/

Comment: Justin Silvers process didn't fix mine either.

Comment: Most anti-anything on a mac is bad news.  I recommend getting rid of:  com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.snowleopard (5.8 - SDK 10.6)  See https://www.paceap.com/ for instructions.  You should use whatever uninstall method the author recommends.

Comment: Try a safe boot.
    Shutdown your machine.  Hold down the shift key.  Poweron.  The boot up will take longer than normal because the filesystem on the startup drive is being checked and repaired as needed.   All about safe mode including what features and apps safe boot leaves out.  Safe boot uses a software driver instead of using your machines video hardware.
      http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455

Comment: yep safe boot was working with lowGraphics. but i did get it working again! i did get rid of a bunch of kexts including PACEsupport when i tried J.Silvers method, that particular one was from 2005. But it didnt work immedt but then i went out to buy a replacement cord as i was going to try to get an old external HD to restore snapshot, then suddenly out of blue it releases CPU again & now working fine again & just need to find correct way to recognise my external HD. It seemed to be processing a lot of `QuickLookSatellite` processes at the time it released & i took a snapshot and will upload.

Comment: thanks for your help @historystamp it should be fine from here. im not going to try mucking more around with PACE uninstalls, i think everything of it is gone now after removing it from /System/Library.

Comment: You may want to consider a full re-install.  I know it's a windozes solution.

Comment: Here is more information on quicklook:  https://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-fix-a-malfunctioning-os-x-quicklook-feature/

Comment: Yeh problem returned again. Etrecheck only shows problematic Daemon/Agent respectively as `org.ntp.ntpd-legacy.plist [not loaded]` and `com.openssh.ssh-agent.plist [loaded]`. I think the consumption of resources related to Quicklook may just be because I had alot of images on desktop and startup creates previews. The source of the problem I've still not isolated. I tried to remove the legacy ntpd but it won't let me as it says system uses it but this says it's been replaced by `timed`: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79934

Comment: These problematics showed when I ran Etrecheck in safe mode too. Though the resource consumption doesn't appear in safe mode but as I said it's not loading many devices in safe mode

Comment: I moved all desktop items into documents instead of desktop and this also didn't fix the problem tho may help with startup speed. Might try a maintenance program. Or will try see if running in verbose mode helps again.

Comment: `GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent` seems to make a lot of calls on startup too so in going to try disabling that: https://fold.it/portal/node/2003861

Comment: I also get this error when booting in verbose mode: `cache matches prelinked text but can't determine if executables are the same (no UUIDs)`. I also notice in console that many programs being loaded on startup say that the class is implemented in two different system locations. `one of the two will be used. Which one is undefined?` `system/library/private frameworks...` and `system/library/coreservices`.

Comment: Which others have had that problem updating to mojave and apparently mojave had option to load existing cache. https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/solved-prelinked-kernel-kernel-cache-error-when-booting-installer.260968/

Comment: I and many others do not recommend "Might try a maintenance program."  These are all scams and many will make your mac worse. Stay with etrecheck and might try malware bytes.

Comment: In verbose mode the prelinked kext that it has problems with is `excludedkextlist`. The OS seems to eventually start working fine (user ~>95%CPU) after several hours of processing the cache. Then I can even sleep. But if I use too memory it can crash on wake-up and I'm back to square one. I did get a backup done though. Might just need to rely on that. Moral.of story don't update without a recent backup on a working drive, and try to avoid security updates after kernel changes.

Comment: Problem is definitely not just my machine as others have had it too. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7814691 others mentioning exactly the problem of CPU being nearly completely consumed by the kernel task too. If and when it resumes proper CPU usage there is no problem with the processing so it's not hardware either. Apple hasn't programmed the update properly for older machines or decrypted machines or dualbootcamped machines.

Comment: quicklook crashes is a common occurance with new updates: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7814691
 `(com.apple.quicklook[3854]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook.` Quicklook crashing may just be a symptom of the crash.

Comment: I was able to restore to a previous snapshot which required wiping the disk, and everything worked again for another 2 days even after 1 sleep, and then crash again after waking from second sleep. Some of the messages upon waking pertain to this error regarding QuickLook though that doesn't imply its the problem. Im wondering if somehow the problem is intiated by sleeping and how that engages with the cache and wakeup and energy management. I run my mac without battery for example.

Comment: but its just really strange that this never happened pre-security-update. so it may have corrupted messed with the caching process.

Comment: I tried removing the last plists that were problematic (the ssh one and the legacy ntpd one) and also the macOSCert plist that was failing. that all did nothing for the CPU problem. I also tried disabling SIP. didn't help either. im now going to try dramatically reinstall the OS. unfortunately taking 2 days to restore a snapshot from recovery mode everytime it crashes is not really a sustainable solution.

Comment: i didnt endup resintalling the OS as i had trouble contacting apples servers againa. but after restoring it again from a pre-runaway snapshot, i then stopped all programs consuming memory and i turned off the Power Nap feature that enables Time Machine, connecting to iCloud et cetera. I suspect that when i was putting to sleep before memory resources were consumed and this feature and maybe the rogue iCredential kext that was frequently not loading were conflicting in a way that consumed all memory and thus all kernel CPU. so my system is working again now.

Comment: as to what caused the intial problem, im still not entirely sure. i suspect now it mightve been the kexts associated with the old mbox maybe conflicting with the Sound Booster driver which im reticent to experiment with anymore since restore. But it couldve been any number of the kexts ive mentioned previous. or it couldve been attempts to synch with iCloud/certificate that was problematic & preventing the cache from being processed.  i havent tested a restart and im reticent to but sleep/awake seemingly works now without fail if i close down memory consuming programs before putting to sleep.

Comment: problem recoccured on waking again. but i managed to rescue it before completely failing. i had left chrome opened (i closed tabs but didnt close the program). there is a memory leak in chrome. `Google Chrome[9118]: objc[9118]: __weak variable at 0x7fb027eb12f0 holds 0x2121212121212121 instead of 0x7fb0239b13d0. This is probably incorrect use of objc_storeWeak() and objc_loadWeak(). Break on objc_weak_error to debug.`. there also seems to be a power memory leak. `PrintUITool[13138]: notify name "com.apple.system.powersources.source" has been registered 20 times - this may be a leak`. ...

Comment: whats interesting is that some of these calls are being done whilst i havent awoke the computer yet. that is, there is significant activity whilst the computer is put asleep. i never knew this.

Comment: this is probably because i have `wake for wifi network access` on.

Comment: issue reoccurred again. sigh. not sure what to do at this point. might try reinstall OS again. this time it seemed to be cloudd making many calls. and secured. tried authenticating in iTunes but it had an unknown error, then I got sms to verify my account...

Comment: and the problem just doesn't occur at all in safe mode. if only Apple could release a tool to help fix such a problem.

Comment: now I find that running `sudo kextcache -prelinked-kernel` results in `/ locked; waiting for lock` as this person also experienced

Comment: this definitely seems to be a problem with the `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.CSConfigDotMacCert` conflicting with kext signing which apple hasn't resolved properly. several others have had some problem. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7802509 https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8014508 http://www.howapple.com/question/58033 https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6435396 all show same failure.