# Can I run my Mac in safe mode but with better graphics bootstrapped?

Tags: high-sierra, graphics, safe-mode

I have an [issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352645/update-screwing-with-encrypted-disk-or-keep-using-windows-boot) with OS but it seems to work stably in safe mode but the graphics are unbearable. For example the graphics flicker a lot when I use GitHub desktop app in safe mode.

Can I run in safe mode but with the graphics working full mode?
But with the other features such as user extensions and caches disabled?

Comment: unfortunately github desktop is an electron app. I had similar graphics issues with slack (also electron) and was able to fix them by disabling hardware acceleration in the Advanced Settings. I don't see a checkbox for that in github desktop.

Comment: Could you recap here in words - what the core “issue” is in the linked question? Maybe we can find out how to just turn that one thing off.

Comment: The core issue is that the kernel task and mdstores begin to run at system using ~95% of CPU. So that basically I can't do anything. I've tried many things to try to isolate what is causing it but still am unsure. Restoring to a snapshot takes a day but returns to a point before the runaway. Only safe mode reliably prevents it from happening.

Comment: note that I have no graphics problems in normal mode, thus its not a graphics nor graphics card problem. so just for a temporary fix this will help me a great deal, especially since I need to do some work in xcode. im reallu surprised I cant find any tutorial or anything explaining how to do this.

Comment: i guess nobody knows how the operating system works anymore